# Hair graying due to water change

Tags: treatment, hair, coloration-discoloration, dyes, chlorine

Recently I moved from India to Riyadh, because the change in water my hair started becoming gray.  Is there any remedy for graying hair due to water change?.

P.S: my age is 26 and am sure that this problem is not related with my age.

Comment: Hi @wingedpanther I edited your post a bit with some changes I thought helped. If you don't think they helped you can always roll them back and edit your own in. Thanks.

Comment: Age happens. Sorry.

Comment: @CareyGregory - You're assuming. What if the OP is 15? 20? Yes, they can be getting prematurely gray, but we would need further information before assuming its age.

Comment: AFAIK Ageing is NOT an actual issue here.I have met many Indians here those having same hair greying issue

Comment: Can you signify what change in water means, please. I assumed it was chlorine, but just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming because I also assumed that something as significant as being 26 would have been mentioned. I'd also like to know why you think it has something to do with water.

Comment: I take bath twice in a day there for I used to wash my hair.I apply shampoo once in a week (no side effects of it because using the same brand in my home country).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Treatment:

- Natural dye: You may not want to use a chemical dye as this will just damage your hair worse.
- [Trying to wash out chlorine buildup](http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Chlorine-Out-of-Your-Hair). Which will not completely reverse the gray hair, but will help heal the hair and keep it healthy.
- [Trimming hair ends.](http://www.livestrong.com/article/188346-how-to-repair-chlorine-damaged-hair/)

> Chlorine and sun can cause split ends, which definitely add to a
>   damaged look.

- Use good hair products to encourage healthy hair and use prevention when around chlorine to prevent extra damage.

There is no complete reversal treatment, because of the [amount of damage](http://www.desalinatedwater.info/chlorine-study.php) it does:

- > The reaction of melanin pigments with chlorine results in change of
  >   hair from natural colour (blond to black) to straw colour of keratin.
- > Chlorine removes natural oils covering hair resulting in loss of hair
  >   shine and flexibility, as well as making them more susceptible to
  >   mechanical damage.

Your hair probably became gray due to the chlorine in the water or other chemicals. Other factors such as diet, stress and etc can cause graying hair, but because you mentioned the water being the reason I focused on that.

[Risk factors for graying hair in chlorine exposed water is:](http://womenshair.about.com/od/healthyhairmaintenance/a/How-Will-Chlorine-Effect-My-Hair.htm)

- Previously damaged hair
- Chemically lightened hair(whitened)
- Dry hair, thin or fine hair
- Permed or relaxed hair

These hair types can get damaged faster and already in a way damaged.

[Prevention:](http://www.swimoutlet.com/guides/how-to-remove-chlorine-from-your-hair)

- Wearing a swimming cap to cover your hair
- Wetting your hair before entering the pool and rinsing and washing well after with a good shampoo and conditioner to protect hair.

Comment: @wingedpanther Glad it could help :)

Comment: I see nothing in your answer that supports the notion that water turns hair gray, chlorine or not. Damage it, yes, but turn it gray? No.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks for your input on my post, however, I thought that I explained it here: " The reaction of melanin pigments with chlorine results in change of hair from natural colour (blond to black) to straw colour of keratin". Is that not enough, as the question is asking for a remedy not pathophysiology and prevention. Even though I did add those both to cover all facets :)

Comment: No, I didn't find your argument compelling that city water with its tiny quantities of chlorine is responsible for turning hair gray. If that were true, there would be a distinct difference in graying between rural and city dwellers, and I don't think there is. I've seen what daily swimming for weeks on end in heavily chlorinated pools will do to light colored hair (turns it green), but I don't think it turns hair gray, and certainly not in the quantities used in drinking water.

Comment: @CareyGregory That is not what I meant xD Ok, I'll try to make it a little more clearer then so everyone can understand. Thanks!